# I need to scrape data from 100 Microsoft Word documents and create a table in a CSV file

Tags: web-scraping, pdf-scraping

I have 100s of Microsoft Word documents. Each document has the same headers. I need to be able to read the data present in those documents and create a table. Output in the form of a CSV file.

I tried to use [Scrapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrapy). But I am new, and I don’t know how to combine all documents at once. And how to proceed after that.

Comment: Isn't Scrapy only for web sites? Perhaps not: *[Extracting text from Microsoft Word files in Python with Scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686285)*

Comment: What language are you planning to use?

Comment: Where are those Word documents? In a file system (locally or network drive)? On a web site?

Comment: Intersection of the tags for Scrapy and Microsoft Word  (about 14,000 each): [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapy+ms-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrapy+ms-word). Result: only one question - [the question I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25686285). Very strange!

Comment: Can you add what you have tried (by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58193509/edit))? E.g. so it is more clear what is meant by *"I don’t know how to combine all documents at once"*.

Comment: The 15 minutes of attention are gone.